# input text sumit to without question mark

Tags: php, html, forms, .htaccess

```
example.com/search/?q=english+videos <- i want to like this after enter -> example.com/search/english+videos
```

i use for that .htaccess file also.. but now want to give url like this from form action. now i use like this form

example.com/search/index.php

```
<form name="menu_search" action="http://www.example.com/search/" method="get">

<input name="q" value="<?php if (!empty($_GET['q'])) { echo $_GET['q']; } ?>" id="videoSearch" />

</form>
```

this is my form action codes only. someone search something its go to `example.com/search/?q=search+something` like that. i want to `example.com/search/search+something`

help me for that. thanks...

/search/.htaccess

```
<Files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
</Files>

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /search/

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)(?:/[^/]+)?/?$ load.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/[^/]+/([0-9]+)/?$ load.php?q=$1&p=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^search/(.*)$ load.php?q=$1 [L]
```

not work last rule how to fix it... `RewriteRule ^search/(.*)$ load.php?q=$1 [L]`

Comment: You can redirect from php to the desired url format, the user will never see `example.com/search/?q=search+something`, just to what you redirect them to.

Comment: yeah. can but have a problem with seo?

Comment: Yes, you would have a problem with seo when redirecting from php. But I don't see Googlebot typing searches in a form.

Comment: @user2094178: Why would a PHP redirect cause SEO problems?

Comment: http://www.brighthub.com/internet/web-development/articles/102786.aspx

Answer (score 1):

A quick and dirty javascript regex you could run is:

```
<script>
function removeQuestionMark()
{
var initialString = "example.com/search/?q=english+videos"; 
initialString  = initialString.replace(/\?/g, '');
console.log(initialString) //This just outputs to new string.
}
</script>
```

Outputs: example.com/search/q=english+videos

..Although that regex would replace all '?'.  A more complex regex would be required to ensure you didn't accident remove one you may want.  It may work for what you want to do.